# Charging 18650 cells in parallel?

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion

I'm trying to Bild my own boombox with an 2*50W Bluetooth amplifier and 10 18650 cells with 3,4Ah each.
I habe bought a tp4056 charging board. The question is if i use 10 betteries connected in parallel and connect the minus and plus to my tp4056 board if it would be able to charge the safely. Or do I need a balance charger?

Comment: No need for balancing *parallel* batteries.

Answer (score 1):

You theoretically don't need anything, but there are drawbacks:

- The charging will be 10 times slower compared to a single cell charged from a TP4056
- A damaged cell will cause the others in the pack to drain and you'll never be able to charge or maintain the pack at full capacity.
- A damaged cell will also cause even more slower charging.

So if you make sure all cells are good, you should be fine for a while.

Comment: Short circuit current can become dangerously (fire) high - fuse each cell with a thin connecting wire / track

Comment: For standard cells, you can use a 3.15A fuse for each cell. That makes sure no accidents happen. A cell can deliver up to 2A safely, so at above 3 means there's a problem and that's where the fuse comes in. http://www.adelaida.ro/images/thumbnails/31/120/zkm1.25a-150x12013366865174fac37b5c0bfe.jpg

Comment: is there other charging modules like TP4056 for charging multiple batteries in parallel?

Comment: I build myself a 12-slot charger using TP4056s. I can charge 12 cells if the PSU is good quality on the 5V rail. https://xaeus.wordpress.com/2018/02/14/12-slot-li-ion-charger-made-out-of-scrap-en/